# ping: Warning: time of day goes back (-203647us), taking countermeasures

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ping, icmp, command

I'm getting the below weird warning message sometimes when pinging to 8.8.8.8 (Occurrence is very low). Any idea about the root cause?

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=111 time=256 ms
ping: Warning: time of day goes back (-203756us), taking countermeasures
ping: Warning: time of day goes back (-203647us), taking countermeasures
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has happened to me on AMD type processors before, where the clocksource wasn't shared between CPUs (it was set to `jiffies` for me).

One of the CPU's was a few jiffies ahead of the other causing the time to go backwards when a process moved between CPUs and compared times.

Try setting the clocksource to `tsc`, `hpet` or `acpi_pm` (in that order) as these clocksources tend to be shared between CPUs.

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
$ echo 'hpet' > /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
```

Alternatively you might have an aggressive stepping policy for your timesync (shouldn't occur really after you've booted). Provide the output of `/etc/ntp.conf` or `/etc/chrony.conf` for more insight.

Comment: Does *"it was set"* mean *"someone had to knowingly configure that"* or is that something a mainline or distribution kernel might automatically chose under any realistic circumstances?

Comment: It was many years ago and the clock source `jiffies` was automatically selected by the kernel as the best one (at the time of boot) as the other clock sources are slower to access so aren't as performative -- yet jiffies also came with the quirk that time flowed backwards which was unacceptable for me.

Comment: @MatthewIfe The `available_clocksource` is already set to `tsc hpet acpi_pm`